# Trying to have a vector containning std::vector<typename>::iterator in a class template

Tags: c++

Assume a class template A:
`typemame<typename T> class A`
I want to have a std::vector member containing another vector's iterators using template parameter T:
`vector<vector<T>::iterator> vec`
However, I'm getting an error "error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’". How can I resolve this?

Some learning material is extremely welcomed as i's still new to c++ template.

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example please.

Comment: `vector<vector<T>::iterator>` -> `vector<typename vector<T>::iterator>`

Comment: Storing iterators is only rarely a good idea. Mostly they're intended to be ephemeral, used to delineate a range when calling an algorithm, and going away when the algorithm returns. Besides, if the code modifies the vector all the iterators become invalid. Usually the better choice is to store an index to each of the target elements; that will survive modification.